# Get architecture type (ABI) to C preprocessor for Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, preprocessor, compiler-flags

I'm trying to control my C code in an Android NDK project depending on the selected ABI library.

As a start, I want the NDK library method to answer, with a string, what ABI that is used. I did a few tries but all fails to deliver the result.

In Application.mk I define
    APP_ABI := all

Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  
include $(CLEAR_VARS)  
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -D$(TARGET_ARCH)  
LOCAL_MODULE    := get_current_abi  
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := get_current_abi.c  
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And finally my C-file looks like this:
    #include 
    #include

```
jstring  
Java_com_example_abifinderlib_AbiFinder_getCurrentAbi(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)  
{  
#if defined armeabi  
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "armeabi");  
#elif defined armeabi-v7a  
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "armeabi-v7a");  
#elif defined mips  
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "mips");  
#elif defined x86  
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "x86");  
#else  
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "unknown");  
#endif  
}
```

Result string is always "unknown" for all architectures. (Tested arm v6 and arm v7 on HW and others on emulator)

Can I see the actual content of the $(TARGET_ARCH) in the make file? Can I run only the preprocessor on my c-file and see the preprocessed result?

Or am I straight of and need a totally different approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CPU Features library for this:

```
#include <cpu-features.h>

AndroidCpuFamily family = android_getCpuFamily();
uint64_t features = android_getCpuFeatures();

if (family == ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_X86) {
} else if (family == ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_MIPS) {
} else if (family == ANDROID_CPU_FAMILY_ARM) {
    if (features & ANDROID_CPU_ARM_FEATURE_ARMv7) {
    }
}
```

([reference](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/getting-started-on-optimizing-ndk-project-for-multiple-cpu-architectures))

Comment: Thanks! However, it feels a bit "not right" not to use the preprocessor to sort these things out. In the end, separate libraries are created for each CPU core, and to compile code for all architectures into all libraries seams a bit superfluous.

Comment: Well, the page I linked to in my answer shows other way of doing this. You could for example do something like `ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DARCH_ARMEABI_V7A
endif`

Comment: Thanks!
I obviously had two errors in my original code. I used "$(TARGET_ARCH)" and not the correct "$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)" and I thought that the value of this variable directly could be used to create a flag.

Comment: This does not work in latest NDK. It won't find include header cpu-features.h

Answer (score 3):

You can use gcc defines like this:

```
#ifdef __i386__
// x86
#elif __x86_64__
// x86_64
#elif __arm__
// armeabi-v7a
#elif __aarch64__
// arm64-v8a
#else
// unknown 
#endif
```